# Kafka Connect vs Akka-stream Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, akka-stream, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

I'm about to implement a streaming infrastructure for my organization based on Kafka and Spark. However i am puzzled at deciding the best way to go when it comes to ingesting data in Kafka.

Many solutions are indeed possible for that task

> 1. Spark itself could be use to read from external source and write to Kafka. I don't want to use that road.
> 2. Kafka Connect
> 3. Kafka Client API (Producer and consumer)
> 4. Akka-Stream Kafka (Which could be though of as Reactive Kafka client as far as I understood but i am not sure)

In order to make my choice, of course i could go on a journey of trying everything out on my own, however, i wonder if anyone already went trough that hurdle.

I am leaning toward (4). Hence to whomever has had some experience with those frameworks for the task at end, i wonder if he could share with me the experience.

In particular, I would like to know the pros and cons observed between using (4) and (2). What makes Kafka Connect a better choice for ingestion. Is it really much more work to use (4). **Is Kafka Connect, reactive ?** **Does Kafka connect handle Back Pressure ?**

Comment: Can you elaborate on "a streaming infrastructure for my organization based on Kafka and Spark. "? This is pretty vague. Something else for you to consider in your research is Kafka Streams.

Comment: Basically I work in a digital library and data center service. We are transition to a linked data infrastructure, meaning converting tones of old data and incoming data. In term of incoming data we talk about millions of records update per day at picks. Kafka will be our fault tolerant with retention buffer, spark streaming our transformer (stream processing engine). In term of downstream system we have already identify 3 stores for the several purpose we have downstream. Does it help ?

Comment: So far after an hour of readying here and there, my understanding is that neither Kafka connect or the Kafka producer and consumer are reactive. So for instance when ingesting data, a pull based approach will be used, while a reactive stream would do a push and pull, allowing more asynchrony, this would result in faster consumption. I am not what happen the other way, when taking data out of Kafka. But I believe somehow something similar is happening, it is simply not reactive (no dynamic push and pull).

Comment: However Kafka connect seems to come with no functional stuff that are nonetheless very important to have. Deployment, config, fault tolerance and so on.

Comment: This is so far my theoretical understanding and based on assumption like I can go about backing it by benchmarking it. But I feel that I still need to clarify my thought a little. If you can help that would be great :)

Comment: Curious which solution did you choose eventually? Did you look at https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/ ?

Answer (score 3):

One way of getting data outside of Kafka into Kafka topics is to write your own service or application. It would use the normal Kafka producer, and in addition to talking to the external system that hosts the data your service or application will also have to track which of the data it has already processed so that upon restart it knows where to begin. It will also have to track that information, potentially break the information into multiple parallel tasks, distribute the tasks amongst multiple processes, and more.

The Akka Streams Kafka framework really is just a reactive variation on the normal producer/consumer APIs. You still have to do all of the same kinds of things mentioned above.

Kafka Connect is a framework for moving data in external systems into Kafka into Kafka, or for moving data inside Kafka into external systems. Kafka Connect does much of the work mentioned above, while delegating to a *connector* for the logic of talking to and working with the external system. Kafka Connect defines *source connectors* and *sink connectors* that each have a slightly different set of responsibilities and functionality. Both are relatively easy to write.

One big advantage of Kafka Connect is the number of available connectors for a wide range of existing systems. If a connector fits, simply install in on your Kafka Connect workers, configure the connector(s) to talk to your external system(s), and then monitor and manage the Kafka Connect workers. No writing code whatsoever. For example, in addition to connectors that copy data from an external system, other connectors monitor the external system for changes and capture the new/changed/deleted data. Sometimes these connectors might just monitor a file system for changes, while others are proper *Change Data Capture* connectors that monitor database management systems for the inserted, updated, and deleted rows/objects/documents. These connectors run forever, constantly watching for any new or changed information and delivering that into the appropriate Kafka topics.

If your data exists in a system for which there isn't a connector, you can either write a source connector or you can write a normal producer application that does much of that work.

In an earlier comment on your question, you talked about Kafka and Kafka Connect are not reactive. They're not, but that doesn't restrict how connectors talk to the external system. There are connectors that establish a connection to an external system, and the external system pushes the information to the client in the connector. Other connector implementations poll (or more often long poll) the external system. It simply depends on what how you talk to the external system.

Now, the Kafka Connect API for source connectors does indeed use a pull model, but basically that's because the Kafka Connect worker is polling the connector for "source records", writing those records to Kafka, and then repeating that process. Each of the connector's tasks run in a separate thread, so this constant looping will go as fast as your connector can produce the data and Kafka Connect can write it to Kafka. Note that your connector will typically block when there are no source records at that time, and then the worker will not simply spin when there is no data.

From a developer perspective, this API remarkably easy to implement. Your connector task is asked for source records, and you return them. Kafka Connect takes care of everything else. And the Kafka Connect framework is written by the Kafka developers using the best practices and already higher performance Kafka producer library.

In terms of fault tolerance, a cluster of Kafka Connect worker will automatically distribute the connectors and tasks across the cluster. If any of the workers fails or can't communicate with the rest of the cluster (e.g., a network partition), the cluster will automatically rebalance the connectors' tasks on the remaining workers. And since Kafka Connect automatically manages/persists the connector's *offsets* (where in the source each message comes from), the restarted tasks will pick up where the others left off, ensuring *at least once* delivery of the data in the external source system.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time. This is a very good explanation, that can serve the all community. The one thing I want to stress is (i) yes Kafka connect provide with many goodies that you would have to re-implement yourself if you were to use the Producer or Consumer API as well as Akka Stream Kafka. However (2) you seem to insinuate that somehow there is no advantage at using a reactive stream, over the implementation of Kafka Connect. I don't think that is completely true. Having a push and pull in front of Kafka should in theory make the ingestion faster.

Comment: However as you said, is it worth the cost of developing everything else on your own. I also don't think so, unless we make it a community project. Meanwhile if you confident of what you insinuate in (2), it would be good to have a slightly deeper comparison.